# Being Matir Family Mesorah

Tags: halacha, minhag, nedarim-shevuot

Does Hataras Nedarim help to be matir all of one's minhagim if the the one being matir has  them in mind?

For example: a sephardi wants to change his minhagim to ashkenazi ones.

Comment: "of the the one being matir has of them in mind" ???? Hataras Nedarim requires you to specify the neder to a court and have them find an "opening" to nullify it.

Comment: Curious who would permit this: " a sephardi wants to change his minhagim to ashkenazi ones."

Comment: I have heard personally from a friend that they sent a letter to Rav Chaim Kanievsky asking if it mutar to change minhagim, Rav Chaim said they could. Also i know a very chovushe Rav whos family mesorah was sfardi, when he was bochur in yeshiva (70's) he asked Rav Elyashiv, and Rav Elyashiv told him he could change